# Разбить сеть на сети меньше

Tags: сеть, tcp-ip, lan

хочу уточнить свои знания, понять, правильно ли я понимаю суть масок.
Допустим у меня есть сеть 192.168.0.0/14
Я хочу разбить ее на сети с маской 24

Получается, что у меня выйдет n-ое количество сетей, по типу:

```
192.168.1.0/24, 192.168.2.0/24 ... 192.168.255.0/24
192.169.1.0/24, 192.169.2.0/24 ... 192.169.255.0/24
192.170.1.0/24, 192.170.2.0/24 ... 192.170.255.0/24
192.171.1.0/24, 192.171.2.0/24 ... 192.171.255.0/24
```

или же я хочу разбить сеть 192.168.0.100/28 на сети с маской /30
Получается, что у меня выйдут сети:

```
192.168.0.100/30, 192.168.0.104/30, 192.168.0.108/30, 192.168.0.112/30
```

Comment: А вопрос-то в чём? *сеть 192.168.0.100/28* Нет такой.

Comment: Да, взял наугад, если я правильно понимаю, там может быть сеть 192.168.0.112/28. Вопрос в том, правильно ли я разбиваю сеть на подсети с нужной маской, что бы использовать в подсетях все ip адреса сети

Comment: *взял наугад* Плохо. Впрочем, мне пофиг, незнание это или неаккуратность, а вот преподаватель может и не захотеть понять... *там должна быть сеть 192.168.0.112/28.* Как вариант. *правильно ли я разбиваю сеть на подсети с нужной маской* В первом примере - да. Второй оценить нельзя - условие некорректно. *что бы использовать в подсетях все ip адреса сети* Сформулируй, как, не деля на подсети, только по тексту задания, определить, сколько подсетей получится.

Comment: Да это не задание, хочу просто сформировать правильное понятие как все работает. Сейчас я смотрю, что в сети 192.168.0.112/28 есть 16 доступных адресов, и если я хочу разбить сеть на две подсети по 8 адресов, то они будут выглядеть как 192.168.0.112/29 и 192.168.0.120/29, т.е. через 8 адресов. С неправильной сетью понял, взял, что бы проще было показать этот отсчет количества адресов, во втором примере там маска  30, значит по 4 адреса, т.е. 192.168.0.112/30, 192.168.0.116/30, 192.168.0.120/30, 192.168.0.124/30

Comment: *в сети 192.168.0.112/28 есть 16 доступных адресов* Нет.

Comment: 192.168.0.112/28 - 14 адресов для использования, адрес самой сети и broadcast, вы про это?

Comment: Да, именно про это. Не я сказал слово "доступные".

Comment: Да, понял, спасибо, теперь разобрался)